# Ruby on Rails - First option of select in Form_for selected and disabled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, form-for

How can I make first option of select `options_from_collection_for_select` as selected and disabled?

I have that code:

```
<%= f.select :state, options_from_collection_for_select(Estate.order(:name), :uf, :name), {}, :id => 'populate_cities' %>
```

And I need that output be:

```
<select id="populate_cities" name="guide_dog_form[state]"><option value="AC">Acre</option>
<option value="Select one option" disabled selected>Select one option</option>
<option value="option1">Option 1</option>
<option value="option2">Option 2</option>
<option value="option3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

I searched and found some answers, but nothing helped me.

Someone can help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use `:prompt => "Placeholder"` if you want the placeholder to show up only when the attribute is nil at the time the form is rendered. It will be selected by default, but nothing will be saved if user submits. If the attribute is already populated [possibly because a) there's a default value or b) it's an edit form], the placeholder item will be omitted from the list entirely.
- Use `:include_blank => "Placeholder"` if you want to include the placeholder in the rendered list at all times.

as per:
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html

Comment: Thanks. So I can't let "Placeholder" as disable?

Comment: No, you can't. But what you can do is to work around it, `options_from_collection_for_select(Estate.order(:name), :uf, :name)` will return an array try to `prepend` the placeholder to this array and use `{ disable: 'place holder'  }` to disable it. It's hackish but it will work.

Comment: Thanks. I’ll try this too.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to select a disabled element (or disable a selected element – if you're looking at it this way).